# What is the sort/display order going from top to bottom of answers on SO?

Tags: support

What is the sort/display order going from top to bottom of answers on SO?

My impression has always been that sort is:

1. correct answer
2. highest votes
3. timestamp

However I noticed some posts where the newest answers were showing up higher than the earlier answers.

Comment: For non-accepted answers with the same score (votes), the ordering is random.

Comment: OIC - TYVM! I never knew :D

Comment: Plus, you can *change* how it sorts via the little buttons in the upper right.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Thats only true for answers posted within 15 minutes of each other IIRC

Comment: @BradleyDotNET ah thanks for the clarification.  I couldn't find the post where I read it.  I guess it was some FGITW post.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET: I don't think the timestamp makes any difference. I found two +14 answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python) that were posted a day apart, and the newer one was sorted higher.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Apparently I stand corrected.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Thanks.  That's really interesting.